# Flask: db is not being referenced properly when importing into my database seeder script

Tags: python, mysql, flask

```
# project\__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from .config import app_config

db = MySQL()

def create_app(config_name):
    
    app = Flask(__name__, 
        instance_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'instance'),
        instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])

    db.init_app(app)

    print(db) # prints <flask_mysqldb.MySQL object at 0x000002A13710FC10>






# project/main.py

from . import db

@main.route('/foobar')
def foobar():

    print(db) # prints <flask_mysqldb.MySQL object at 0x000002A13710FC10>






# project/database/seed_shipment.py

from project import create_app, db


def foo():
    .
    .
    .

def goo()
    .
    .
    .

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')

    app = create_app(config_name)

    cursor = db.connection.cursor()

    print(db) # prints <flask_mysqldb.MySQL object at 0x000002056B4EFD60>

    print(db.connection) # returns None


    for x in range(20):

        # code which generates dummy data using foo() and goo()
        
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO shipment (column1, column2) VALUES (%s)", (var1, var2))


    db.connection.commit()
```

My database connection works fine when I host the app and carry out CRUD operations using the interface in my browser. Such as login, sign up, create a shipment.

Note that I am not executing `flask run` from my terminal but instead `python -m project.run`, here is the code of this script:

```
# project/run.py

import os

from . import create_app

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV')

app = create_app(config_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

However, when I run `python -m project.database.seed_shipment` db seems to reference a different MySQL instance which has no connection. See the print results in the comments in my code.

Comment: What is the content of ```from . import db```?

Comment: ```from . import db``` references the ```db``` instance in ```__init__.py```. This is successful in main.py but fails in ```tests/seed_shipment.py```. Possibly because main.py consists of views and thus its functions are communicating with the Flask instance.

Comment: With this comment, you have solved the mystery yourself - I think.

Answer (score 0):

> My database connection works fine when I host the app and carry out CRUD operations using the interface in my browser. Such as login, sign up, create a shipment.

This indicates to me that you are correctly connecting to your db for each request.

> However, when I run python -m project.database.seed_shipment db seems to reference a different MySQL instance which has no connection. See the print results in the comments in my code.

This, on the other hand, indicates to me that you are not connecting to your db when you directly execute `seed_shipment` - in fact, you seem to reference something different (as you write). In other words, `db = MySQL()` is not called.

I recommend that you try the following.

```py
# project\__init__.py

from flask import Flask, g
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from .config import app_config


def create_app(config_name):
    
    app = Flask(__name__, 
        instance_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'instance'),
        instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])

    # this here is just to register the teardown context and some variables ....
    MySQL(app)

    return app


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = MySQL().connection.cursor()

    return g.db
```

That way, `MySQL(app)` is always executed when you call `create_app`. Now, you should be able to simply call `get_db` each time you want your db.

Comment: You did not declare ```db``` anywhere. How would I reference the connection in my ```main.py``` file with your approach?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please have a look. There is also another way, but I will leave it for now.